# Set a $_POST variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I set a `$_POST` variable using jQuery or JavaScript, and without using an Ajax library?

Comment: Please, no need to say it three times! We understand  Instead of repetition, a few more details could help. Is this with a form on the page, or would you like to send a request to another page or domain? By "Ajax library", does that mean you can't use Ajax at all, or just not `$.ajax`?

Answer (score 2):

jQuery is the library, ajax is not. Ajax is an implementation of the `XHR Object` written as a jQuery method.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'path/to/my/controller.ext',
    data: 'myvar=something'
});
```

PHP.

```
if(isset($_POST['myvar'])):
    //you now have reference to myvar, which has a value of something.
endif;
```

Comment: Nevermind my answer, I read that you needed to "get" a $_POST variable, not "set". +1

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with javascript very simply by adding an `onclick="click();"` property to the button or link you are trying to get, then writing a small `function click() {` to handle the `var value = document.GetElementById('textBoxId').value`.

EDIT: This is to "get" a variable, not "set" a variable, but you can still use these ideas to perform an action based on the user clicking the button and then retrieving the value of the field.